# saveDocument() function from NSIWebBrowserPersist

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla

As far as I know, 'save as..' feature from Firefox browser also uses this function, so I tried to implement this function in my code.

All went well except the saved css and javascript files. They contain weird numbers. 'Save as..' from Firefox does not do this. Did I do something wrong?

What I did:

```
webBrowserPersist.saveDocument(content.document, file, dir, null, null, null);
```

Did I miss something? Am I supposed to change MIME or encoding flags? (I don't understand these 4th and 5th parameters by the way)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: UPDATE: I tried to change document.content to document, the files are finally readable, except that it won't download js and image files....

Comment: Probably need to use the `ENCODE_FLAGS_ABSOLUTE_LINKS` flag or some other flags. Ill test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIWebBrowserPersist#saveDocument%28%29

The fourthargument is for putting encoding flags. So from the page above (we look for flags that have the word encode in it), we could pass to it like:

```
persist = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedding/browser/nsWebBrowserPersist;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIWebBrowserPersist);

persist.saveDocument(gBrowser.contentDocument, localFile, dataPath, persist.ENCODE_FLAGS_ENCODE_BASIC_ENTITIES, null, null);
```

For fifth its formating flags. We can use multiple by joing them with bitwise or operator so like:

```
persist = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedding/browser/nsWebBrowserPersist;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIWebBrowserPersist);

persist.saveDocument(gBrowser.contentDocument, localFile, dataPath, null, persist.PERSIST_FLAGS_FORCE_ALLOW_COOKIES | persist.PERSIST_FLAGS_BYPASS_CACHE, null);
```

stuff like that

and last argument is for how you want to wrap it. i guess there are some wrapping flags. maybe try passing a number.

Working example:

```
var file = "c:\\test2.htm";
var data = "c:\\test2_data";
localFile = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
           .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
localFile.initWithPath(file)

dataPath = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
          .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile)
dataPath.initWithPath(data)

persist = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedding/browser/nsWebBrowserPersist;1"]
         .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIWebBrowserPersist);

persist.saveDocument(gBrowser.contentDocument, localFile, dataPath, null, null, null);
```

Stolen from: https://github.com/aptana/Jaxer/blob/f7994fc75a768c9873f094e29868c22e88b46b50/server/src/mozilla/embedding/qa/jstests/nsIWebBrowserPersistTest2.txt#L77

---

By the way this is what the save us function uses from the menu:

```
/*
function saveDocument(aDocument, aSkipPrompt)
{
  if (!aDocument)
    throw "Must have a document when calling saveDocument";

  // We want to use cached data because the document is currently visible.
  var ifreq =
    aDocument.defaultView
             .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor);

  var contentDisposition = null;
  try {
    contentDisposition =
      ifreq.getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindowUtils)
           .getDocumentMetadata("content-disposition");
  } catch (ex) {
    // Failure to get a content-disposition is ok
  }

  var cacheKey = null;
  try {
    cacheKey =
      ifreq.getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation)
           .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebPageDescriptor);
  } catch (ex) {
    // We might not find it in the cache.  Oh, well.
  }

  internalSave(aDocument.location.href, aDocument, null, contentDisposition,
               aDocument.contentType, false, null, null,
               aDocument.referrer ? makeURI(aDocument.referrer) : null,
               aDocument, aSkipPrompt, cacheKey);
}
*/
```

`saveDocument(gBrowser.contentDocument, true)`

this is the function that the save menu item uses.

Comment: Apparently I can't ignore the arguments, if I do that, I get error:
NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS: Not enough arguments [nsIWebBrowserPersist.saveDocument]

I tried to change document.content to document, the files are finally readable, except that it won't download js and image files....

Comment: o you're right. i updated it. i tested it this time too. i ran it from scratchpad so i wanted to save the document i was currently viewing so i set the first argument to `gBrowser.contentDocument`

Comment: ok I'll try it. 
Btw `gBrowser.contentDocument` still encodes external files.

Comment: i messed around with the flags i couldnt figure out how to get your initial way to download with css and js etc. we have to dig into this saveDocument function the saveas thing uses, it probably does use this persist thing somewhere inside, just gotta keep back tracking it on mxr

Comment: Where did you get this function btw?

Comment: I used [DOM Inspector and Element Inspector add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/collections/Noitidart/ff/). Opened up file menu then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Click</kbd> on the menu item. Then searched for it's command on mxr.mozilla.org release branch.

Comment: Hey man I noticed yo uaccepted this, what was here that answered your problem? I was just trying to guide you but the comment section wouldn't let me post this much detail. I would prefer you unaccpted and waited for a real solution. Or if you came up with solution based off this just give it an up vote and post your solution on this topic plz.

Comment: @notidart
I just used the function you gave me.
It works exactly the same as the original.
Now I'm trying to modify this function and have a lot of questions but I think it is OOT if it's discussed here....

Comment: Oh dang ok well make some topics :) lots of others here better than me that can help :) glad to hear my fuxn helpd :)

Answer (score 3):

for this problem you must user PERSIST_FLAGS_AUTODETECT_APPLY_CONVERSION property:

```js
var persist = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedding/browser/nsWebBrowserPersist;1"].
createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIWebBrowserPersist);

var localPath = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].
createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);

localPath.initWithPath("\home\user\test");
var localFile = localPath.clone();
localFile.append("myfile.html");

persist.persistFlags=persist.PERSIST_FLAGS_AUTODETECT_APPLY_CONVERSION;

persist.saveDocument(contentDoc, localFile, localPath, 0 ,  null, null);
```