# Using Downloads.jsm to save complete web-page

Tags: firefox-addon

We are porting our extension to multiprocess Firefox and I found that     `nsIWebBrowserPersist.saveDocument()` can no longer be used since it takes DOM document as a parameter.

I used `nsIWebBrowserPersist` to save a complete web page along with images, styles and scripts stored in a _files folder. I consider using     `nsIWebBrowserPersist.saveURI()` as a replacement but [the documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIWebBrowserPersist) contains a warning that `Downloads.createDownload()` should be used instead.

Maybe any other options?

Comment: A user by the name of [rpgs_palyer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1093884/rpgs-player?tab=questions) posted up a few questions on this topic, check out his profile for questions. Heres one: [saveDocument() function from NSIWebBrowserPersist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570831/savedocument-function-from-nsiwebbrowserpersist/27292413#27292413)  if they still dont answer your question let me know here and ill try to help

Comment: As I see all the questions about using nsIWebBrowserPersist and not about how to deal with it in multiprocess Firefox.

Comment: I think the Downloads.createDownload method wants us to XHR from cache the file and then save that, what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gBrowser.selectedBrowser.contentDocumentAsCPOW` to pass the document of the selected tab. This will work on e10s enabled Firefox, even with windows explicitly opened as non-e10s.

Comment: As far as I understand that would rely on [compatibility shims](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox/Limitations_of_chrome_scripts#Compatibility_shims) which I would like to [avoid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#multiprocessCompatible).

Comment: This is what Nightly does.

Comment: Thanks @paa for sharing that this is what Nightly does, I was also avoiding this method because i wanted to avoid compatability shims, but if thats how nightly does it, the compat shims must not be so dreadful.